# Delete recursively all files which have a specific HEX content

Tags: command-line, files, delete, find

I need to delete recursively all files which have the following HEX content: `\xDE\xAD\xBA\xAD`

Can you please suggest a terminal command which will do that?

Comment: Are the files in a know place or have to be search for first then deleted?

Answer (score 1):

To locate these files, you can use this command:

```
LC_ALL=C grep -Fral $'\xDE\xAD\xBA\xAD'
```

Setting `LC_ALL=C` is a safety measure to make sure no multi-byte behavior or any other weirdness kicks in. It is probably not needed, although might speed up the operation.

`grep` searches for files matching a certain pattern.

`-F` tells it that the pattern is a simple string rather than a regular expression. It is not needed here, although would be needed if your patter contained characters that have special meaning in regular expressions.

`-r` tells grep to operate recursively.

`-a` tells it to process all files (even ones that it guesses as binary).

`-l` tells it to list the filenames only, not the matching line(s).

The order of these four options doesn't matter.

`$'\xDE...'` tells `bash`, your command line interpreter to place those actual bytes in the command line before starting `grep`. That is, `grep` already sees the four raw bytes instead of the `\xDE...` *string*.

If you're satisfied with a result after a dry run (highly recommended), you should add another `-z` option to `grep` so that its output is delimited by NUL characters rather than newlines, and then pipe the output to `xargs`:

```
LC_ALL=C grep ... -z ... | xargs -0 rm -i --
```

`xargs` passes all the values it sees from its standard input into parameters of the `-i` command.

`xargs`'s `-0` correspond's to `grep`'s `-Z`: the input is expected to be NUL-separated.

`rm`'s `-i` makes `rm` interactive, remove this if you're absolutely sure you want all such files to be removed without confirmation, you know for sure what you're doing, you do have a backup, and you've verified that I haven't made a significant mistake here that could lead to unexpectedly deleting files. :-)

`rm`'s `--` makes sure `rm` doesn't process any of its remaining arguments as command line parameters, just in case `grep`'s first match would be a filename beginning with `-`.

Answer (score 0):

Run the grep command first to see the files of interest:

```
grep -REl '\\xDE\\xAD\\xBA\\xAD' /path/to/file/location/
```

Then using `rm`:

```
rm -rf $(grep -REl '\\xDE\\xAD\\xBA\\xAD' /path/to/file/location/)
```

Information:

`-R`: used to search a location with grep

`-E`: grep's extended regex option

`\`: greps regex escape character, used to make sure `\` is included in the search.

`-l`: grep's option to list the files where the said pattern have been found